# Edit dataframe values in a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need the values in group C to be in 200 intervals instead of 100 in Col3. I have a lot of columns in my actual dataframe but see below for simple example

Original DF:

```
Group    Col2       Col3
 A        50         44
 A        3          144
 B        200        500
 B        4.5        600
 B        89         700
 B        48         800
 C        443        220
 C        54         320
 C        63         420
 C        7          520
```

Desired DF:

```
Group    Col2       Col3
 A        50         44
 A        3          144
 B        200        500
 B        4.5        600
 B        89         700
 B        48         800
 C        443        220
 C        54         420
 C        63         620
 C        7          820
```

Where Group C is now in increments of 200 instead of 100 as in the original DF. Any suggestions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean-indexing + `range()`:

```py
mask = df["Group"].eq("C")
df.loc[mask, "Col3"] = df.loc[mask, "Col3"] + range(0, mask.sum() * 100, 100)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Group   Col2  Col3
0     A   50.0    44
1     A    3.0   144
2     B  200.0   500
3     B    4.5   600
4     B   89.0   700
5     B   48.0   800
6     C  443.0   220
7     C   54.0   420
8     C   63.0   620
9     C    7.0   820
```

Comment: This worked. A side question -- with the mask variable, how/is it possible to add two conditions? Example group column = "C" and column B > 20?

Comment: @dmd7, You can combine the two conditions with and operator `mask = (df["Group"].eq("C")) &(df['B'].gt(20))`

Comment: @ThePyGuy Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.groupby()` + `transform()` + `cumcount()`, as follows:

```
g = df.groupby('Group')['Col3']
df.loc[df['Group'] == 'C', 'Col3'] = g.transform('first') + g.cumcount() * 200
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  Group   Col2  Col3
0     A   50.0    44
1     A    3.0   144
2     B  200.0   500
3     B    4.5   600
4     B   89.0   700
5     B   48.0   800
6     C  443.0   220
7     C   54.0   420
8     C   63.0   620
9     C    7.0   820
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple math:

```
df['col3'] = df['col3'].where(df['Group'].ne('C'), df['col3']*2-220)
```

Of course, 220 need not to be hardcoded, you can use `df.query('Group == "C"')['col3'].min()`